# How can I increase Polygon area and draw on center of image in python?

Tags: python, shapefile

I have draw Polygon area on image but it will draw on below side corner of image and small area. How can I increase Polygon area and draw on center of image in python.

I am using below code.

```
import shapefile
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
r = shapefile.Reader("K:\NEW_GIS\NEW Data\Garpani_NLRMP_Data\Shape files\Garpani_corrected")
shapes = r.shapes()
xdist = r.bbox[2] - r.bbox[0]
ydist = r.bbox[3] - r.bbox[1]
iwidth = 800
iheight = 800
xratio = iwidth/xdist
yratio = iheight/ydist
#print xratio
#print yratio
pixels = []
for x,y in r.shapes()[39].points:
    px = int(iwidth - ((r.bbox[2] - x) * xratio))
    py = int((r.bbox[3] - y) * yratio)
    print px
    print py
    pixels.append((px,py))

img = Image.new("RGB", (iwidth, iheight), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.polygon(pixels,outline="black", fill="white")
img_new_name="C:/example/Garpani_corrected.png"
```

[image]

```
img.save(img_new_name)
```

Comment: You had tags for QGIS and ArcGIS for Desktop but do not mention either in you question body so I removed them.

Comment: It looks like your bounding box is too large, try outputting that as text and compare that to what you see in another viewer (QGIS for example) and see if the bounding box obtained by shapefile is correct.

Comment: I guess you only need the bbox of polygon nr. 39: `myBox = (r.shapes()[39]).bbox` and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for replay, How can i set outline width of polygon in python

Answer (score 1):

I think you're creating a bounding box for your whole dataset, then drawing only one feature.

Try doing the following:

- First, loop over your feature of interest and build up the bounding box
- Next buffer those coordinates by, say, 20% (increase the max and decrease the min by 20% of the total difference)
- now use your current logic to define your area of interest (image) coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for replay, How can i set outline width of polygon in python

Comment: You'd better look into the documentation for PIL, mate.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the initial tags, I present an approach I used in QGIS

The steps are:

- get the area of interest with a  QgsExpression
- get the ids and select the features
- get the bounding box of selected features
- add a margin around the selection (optional)
- Update the canvas and redraw it

Code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
expr = QgsExpression('"myfield" = %s' %(my_value))
it = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
box = layer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
box.scale(2,box.center()[0], box.center()[1])

iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```